# Raspberry Pi 4 incorrect password error after unexpected restart

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, login

I am using Raspberry Pi4 with 64bit OS (raspberry pi os and not NOOBS) on a 32G microSD. It was working just fine before it rebooted by itself duing an `scp` operation from a remote computer. After that, the password (default *raspberry*) is not accepted. I have access to /boot and /root partitions from the microSD on a Linux desktop.

Here is the content of /boot/cmdline.txt:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=96e8f372-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

I tried different approaches:

- appended `init=/bin/sh` to the file cmdline.txt and `boot_delay=1` to config.txt. **Result**: the Pi stuck at rainbow screen for ever and never moves to cmd to change the password.
- appended `init=/bin/bash` to the file cmdline.txt. **Result:** the same as above (stuck at rainbow screen).
- appended `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to the file cmdline.txt. **Result:** the same as above (stuck at rainbow screen).
- appended `systemd.unit=rescue.target` to the file cmdline.txt. **Result:** the Pi stops at cmd page with `cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. press enter to continue`. By pressing enter, it normally boots and shows the login page (password incorrect).
- Pressing/holding shift at startup. **Result:** doesn't work as it is not NOOBs. Boots and shows the login page.

**What else can I do to recover?** I am trying not to do a fresh image installation as I have various libraries installed.

Comment: Possible keyboard language issue?  If you can enter the user name anywhere check if it recognises what you type as 'raspberry'.

Comment: That's was not the issue. Other than through connected monitor/keyboard, I also tried connecting to the pi via ssh remotely - same error.

Comment: What you **SHOULD** have done is restore from your backup. Recovering from a crash leaves your system in an indeterminate state.  With luck it works, but you may find other issues later.

Comment: Was that `scp` command modifying any system directories by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After a few trials, I finally fixed it. I will write the steps below for anyone with the same issue:**

1. Unlock and enable `root` (superuser) by manually editing the file `/etc/shadow`. There is an entry for `root` which should be similar to `root:*:0:0...`. Simply remove the `*` and save the file. **Note:** copying an existing password (for example from user pi which should be similar to `pi:$X$SK5xfLB1ZW:0:0...` will less likely seem to be a workaround!).
2. Append `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to the file /boot/cmdline.txt and save it.
3. Insert the microSD back in the pi, start and wait for the command-line black-screen. When asked for `root` password, skip by pressing ENTER as you currently have no password set for `root`.
4. Once you gained `root` access, change the password for user `pi` by the command `passwd pi`. Then type `sync` and then reboot by `exec /sbin/init`.

The four steps above might solve the issue and your new password for user `pi` will be accepted at login page. **In my case, however, it **DID NOT**!** So I changed the user from `pi` too `root` and left the password blank. Once logged in, I opened a terminal and changed the password for user `pi` (`passwd pi`) and restarted the Pi.

The last step fixed the issue and I could login normally as user `pi`!

Comment: If this solution worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. Or it'll keep popping up on the list again and again.

Answer (score 0):

With locked root user account /bin/sh will no do any good. So in addition to what @zlg have written I can add, that If you have **USB dongle bluetooth keyboard** like me the one thing that worked was to add `systemd.unit=rescue.target`. Most of the places that mentioned that you need USB keyboard were not specifically mentioning that it should be wired keyboard (as it seems). I'm not quite sure why wired keyboard and USB dongle bluetooth one are different as I think from USB point of view they should be the same, but I'm no expert. So it seems that 'rescue.target' allow drivers (udev) to loads as opposed to 'systemd.unit=emergency.target' and then you can type in the console, instead of sadly looking at the blinking cursor and not being able to do anything